# Get data from the middle of JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a file with JSON:

```
{
    "first":{"a":[{"b":[{"c":"AAA"}]}],"d":111},
    "second":{"a":[{"b":[{"c":"BBB"},{"c":"CCC"}]}],"d":222}
}
```

I need to save it with flat text structure, something like that:

```
111
    AAA
222
    BBB
    CCC
```

How do I iterate through JSON? All I've managed to do is:

```
import json

file_json = open('1.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
data = json.load(file_json)
file_json.close()

file_new = open('data.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')

for number in data:
    file_new.write(number + "\n")

file_new.close()
```

I get

```
first
second
```

But how do I get rest of the data?
I tried `for number, data_rest in data:`, but it get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular structure, you can get the elements you're looking for from

```
>>> d = {
...     "first":{"a":[{"b":[{"c":"AAA"}]}],"d":111},
...     "second":{"a":[{"b":[{"c":"BBB"},{"c":"CCC"}]}],"d":222}
... }
>>> d['first']['d']
111
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.values() for x in d['first']['a'][0]['b']))
['AAA']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.values() for x in d['second']['a'][0]['b']))
['BBB', 'CCC']
```

When you're all said and done, it might look something like this:

```
from itertools import chain
import json

s = '''{
    "first":{"a":[{"b":[{"c":"AAA"}]}],"d":111},
    "second":{"a":[{"b":[{"c":"BBB"},{"c":"CCC"}]}],"d":222}
}'''

from collections import OrderedDict
d = json.loads(s,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)  #Keep order of dictionaries

for subdict in d.values():
    print subdict['d']
    chained = chain.from_iterable(x.values() for x in subdict['a'][0]['b'])
    for item in chained:
        print '\t',item
```